# jQuery - send multiple URLs to multiple text input fields

Tags: jquery, input

I'm having a problem with jQuery that I thought would be simple, but I still haven't found a solution.

I have an upload form for users to upload images in WordPress, and when a user clicks "insert into post" the url of the uploaded image is supposed to go into a text input field.

I can get 1 to work fine, but when I have multiple upload buttons with multiple input fields the image url is send to the last text input only.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //MEDIA UPLOADER
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      //Opens the upload dialog box when the button is clicked
      jQuery('#wpsa_slide_<?php echo $slidenumber; ?>_button').click(function() {
      formfield = jQuery('#wpsa_slide_<?php echo $slidenumber; ?>').attr('name');
      tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
      return false;
  });
  //Sends the uploaded/selected file URL to the text input field
  window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
     imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
     jQuery('#wpsa_slide_<?php echo $slidenumber; ?>').val(imgurl);
     tb_remove();
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
```

This selects all the images in your html and gets the src attribute of *the first one* in this collection. Probably the problem is there...

Comment: thanks...is there a way to assign an id or class to make it unique or is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: actually I am getting the correct image url, but for instance if I have 3 input fields, and I want the image url to go the 2nd input field, the new url is instead passed to the 3rd one...hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your html?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{    
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length+1;
    var row=0;
    var click=0;
    for(var num=0;num<lastRow;num++)
    {
        row+=1;
        jQuery('#upload_image_button'+row).click(function() {
            formfield = jQuery('#my_meta[image'+row+']').attr('name');
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
            click=this.id;
            return false;
        });
    }

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        click = click.substring(19);
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        var field = 'upload_image_hide'+click+'';
        jQuery('#'+field).val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }

});
```